# How to update Column children onDragComplete in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a layout in my flutter-web with drag and drop functionalities. Once the drag is completed, I want to show the information regarding dragged element in a Column via API.

```
child: Container(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
               margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 5),
               color: Colors.white,
               child: Single Child ScrollView(
                 child: Column(
                   children: <Widget>[params],
                 ),
               )
               //    child:widgetListtile,
               )
```

I want to update the params  via

```
onDragCompleted:() {
    params=fetchAttributes(id);
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use GestureDetactor  `GestureDetector(onDragCompleted: params=fetchAttributes(id), child: )`